Why does react-native-gesture-handler module includes native code?
Noticing that RNGH module includes folders named Android and Apple with .java and .m files inside, how is this accomplished? Can I write some of the React Native code in Native code and publish them as npm modules?
Many of the React Native js code have bugs or huge performance loss, especially with those who use gesture, storage, video or animation. I was expecting to rewrite those in native code without republish the app.
